# How to interpret shimmy in the next sentence: "I shimmied onto the Spray Park Trail"

Tags: meaning-in-context

How to interpret shimmy in the next sentence:
"Donning my pack and trekking poles, I shimmied onto the Spray Park Trail, a six-mile singletrack that promised a waterfall and majestic views."

Is shimmied, in this particular case, refers to the walkway leading onto the Spray Park Tray being not straight, but kind of undulating, making him walk up and down along the way (shimmying)?

Answer (score 1):

This use of the verb '[to shimmy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shimmy#Verb)' is idiomatic and somewhat non-standard. Literally, the speaker is simply saying that they got onto the Spray Park Trail. However, by using the word 'shimmy' (which usually refers to a kind of dance), the speaker is suggesting that they got there **briskly**, **jauntily**, or **in a care-free way**. It might suggest that the speaker climbed up something to get there (or in general increased their altitude), but, to my ear, the connotation is more one of attitude than of manner.

Answer (score 1):

***The Shimmy*** (sometimes spelled *shemmy*) was a ragtime dance of the 1920s in which the whole body shakes and vibrates.

The OED describes it thus: *To shake, quiver, vibrate, to progress hastily or irregularly.*

> 1919   A. J. Piron (title of song)    I wish I could shemmi like my
> sister Kate.

Does that help?

Comment: Right, the sentence is meant to be funny.